# remove comma from csv row list

Tags: python, csv, file

My csv file row - [image]

My code-

```
with open("G:/Downloads/whatever - Sheet1 (1).csv", 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
        for row in csv_reader:
            # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
            row = row.replace(",", "")
            docs = list(nlp.pipe(row))
```

I am getting the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'.
How do I solve it? Mainly I want to remove all the comma from csv file.

Comment: What's the point of having a _comma_ separated file without commas?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to get the output of your csv without the commas, here your row variable doesn't contain commas but instead contains the data in a list as in:

```
[item1, item2, item3]
```

if you want to convert that into a string, you would want to do something like:

```
output = ''.join(row)
```

to replace your

```
row = row.replace(",","")
```

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The row is a list of column values for that particular line. You don't need to replace the commas, instead read the values in the list and concatenate to create a single string and pass it to nlp.

```
with open("G:/Downloads/whatever - Sheet1 (1).csv", 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
        for row in csv_reader:
            # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
            # concatenate the string to a single string
            concatenated_value = ''.join(row)
            
            docs = list(nlp.pipe(concatenated_value))
```